# Choose noSQL for a big security project - a lot or write, some read

Tags: database, nosql, bigdata

I need some help choosing a noSQL for a security project that collects a lot of data.
It suppose to write to the noSQL a lot of data from many users, we will need to aggregate it, and we need to be able to fetch the data with sorting capabilities (for example: get some reports for top  50 users...) .

That means we have a lot of data inserts (no update) and sometimes read.

I saw a lot of noSQLs and I couldn't find one answer.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Mongodb** is the most fashionable noSQL DB nowadays. This means great tools and makes easier to find skilled advice. It supports all the features I think you would need (sharding, Map/Reduce, noSQL):

> project that collects a lot of data

Eventually you'll need to distribute your data amongst different machines and mongo has sharding for that.

> we will need to aggregate it

You'll greatly profit from map/reduce for that

> we need to be able to fetch the data with sorting capabilities

noSQL takes care of that

Comment: Thanks for your answer. what do you say about cassandra and hbase?

Comment: If you need a very fast DB then Cassandra and HBase are faster than MongoDB but for querying your data I would say MongoDB is friendlier, specially if you come from an SQL background. This is a good comparison of the three in terms of performance: http://www.networkworld.com/news/tech/2012/102212-nosql-263595.html